# MDX calculated measure parallelperiod multiple role playing dimensions

Tags: mdx

// Hello, rather than create a different measure for each role plying dimension I would like to have one generic measure.

// I have two role playing dimensions : [Order Date] and [Supply Date] both derived from [Dim Date].

// this works

```
with member Measures.[X] as
(
parallelPeriod( [Order Date].[Calendar].[YYYY],1,[Order Date].[Calendar].currentmember) ,[Measures].[Qty]
)
select 
{
    [Measures].[Qty]
    ,[Measures].[X]
} on 0
,nonempty( [Order Date].[Calendar].[YYYY] ) on 1
from [JSTEST]
```

// I would like to modify the above measure so that it can be called for any role playing date dim.  The following does not work.

```
with member Measures.X as
(
parallelPeriod( 
                    ((NULL:LinkMember( [Order Date].[Calendar].currentmember, [Order Date].[Calendar].[YYYY]))
                         ,(LinkMember( [Supply Date].[Calendar].currentmember, [Supply Date].[Calendar].[YYYY]) : NULL))
    ,1
    ,{NULL:[Order Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember} * {NULL:[Supply Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember})
    ,[Measures].[Qty]
)
select 
{
    [Measures].[Fact Data Count]
    ,[Measures].[X]
} on 0
,nonempty( [Supply Date].[Calendar].[YYYY] ) on 1
from [JSTEST]
```

// Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say it "does not work", could you be more clear, please? Can you post your sample data, the result you are getting, and the result you want to get.